# How to provide a proper type for use of generic impl?

Tags: generics, rust, associated-types

I'm trying to build up my intuition for associated types in Rust. In my experiments I build this (nonsensical) combination of generics and impl.

```
struct MyStruct<T>{
    t:T
}

trait MyTrait {
    type T1;
    fn tt(x:Self::T1) -> MyStruct<Self::T1>;
}

impl<T> MyTrait for MyStruct<T> {
    type T1=T;
    fn tt(a:Self::T1) -> MyStruct<Self::T1> {
        MyStruct{t:a}
    }

}
```

It compiles, but the problem is that I can't use 'tt' function.

```
fn main() {
    let x = MyTrait::tt(1);
}
```

causing an error: `cannot infer type`.

I've tried my options to provide type hints for Rust, but more I try the less audible (for me) error messages become.

Can someone provide me with example of use `MyTrait::tt` function from above, or is this a dead end? If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with using something like `MyTrait::tt(1)` is that the actual type that implements `MyTrait` can't be deduced from the argument `1`. You could, for example, implement `MyTrait` for `String`, but make `T1` be `i32`. With that setup, `MyTrait::tt(1)` could refer to `<String as MyTrait>::tt` (using the fully qualified method call syntax). On the other hand, you could also implement `MyTrait` for `i32` with `T1 = i32`. Then `MyTrait::tt(1)` could also refer to `<i32 as MyTrait>::tt`.

```rust
impl MyTrait for String {
    type T1 = i32;
    fn tt(x: i32) -> MyStruct<i32> {
        MyStruct { t: x }
    }
}

impl MyTrait for i32 {
    type T1 = i32;
    fn tt(x: i32) -> MyStruct<i32> {
        MyStruct { t: x }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 47_i32;

    // let y = MyTrait::tt(x);
    // That could refer to either of the following
    let y = <String as MyTrait>::tt(x);
    let z = <i32 as MyTrait>::tt(x);

    // Of course, you don't need the fully qualified syntax
    // all the time.
    let y2 = String::tt(x);
    let z2 = i32::tt(x);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62c427d420ab7da94de0bf40580c2666)

This behavior might be improved with smarter trait solvers since in your particular case, the only applicable implementation is the one on `MyStruct<i32>`. But for now, I'd just use `<MyStruct<i32> as MyTrait>::tt(1)` or simply `MyStruct::tt(1)`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = <MyStruct<i32> as MyTrait>::tt(1);
    let x = MyStruct::tt(1);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=057442aaf499087133d4a524c8b368c3)

To learn more about traits and fully qualified syntax take a look in [The Book's chapter on advanced traits.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will continue to fight through this part. I have no idea why it's so hard to grasp.